# "SSL is required" exception while requesting OAuthRequest Token using Twitter4J library

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I was trying this sample application provided [here](https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample), I am getting "SSL is required" exception in this particular piece of code

```
private void askOAuth() {
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Const.CONSUMER_KEY);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Const.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
        twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Const.CALLBACK_URL);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please authorize this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

when `twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(Const.CALLBACK_URL);` is executed I get this exception.

I have configure consumer key, consumer secret and callback url to that of my application.

Answer (score 4):

Got this solved 
If you are using twitter4j version 3 or less that in ConfigurationBuilder you have to set

```
configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
```

because twitter has made ssl as mandatory to make API request

for twitter4j version 4, by default ssl is used.