# Get tweets using Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have a java program for fetching my tweets and below is the code

```
public class TwitterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        //  My Applications Consumer and Auth Access Token
        //twitter.setOAuthConsumer("67MIcbC1X6mbpaEqxa7YTd1hDPIdLb5bLKf4TxIRLAsX63DgFQ", "7HHjSHJ6Rjxx4ASC2465AlWBG");
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken("s1y1iAhG5nsXTrE9OVAsqMtqiLIP4QKT8CmTRVgV9LC3O", "110445397-Cf3l9NAK4iD8VAERXp0ZMKnAfWx9KywuJs3OSdkF"));

        try {

            ResponseList<Status> a = twitter.getUserTimeline(new Paging(1,5));

            for(Status b: a) {
                System.out.println(b.getText());
            }

        }catch(Exception e ){

        }

    }
}
```

Below is the error which i get

```
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b64d2231 or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=309f0452
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b64d2231-309f0452], statusCode=403,     message=SSL is required, code=92, retryAfter=-1,    rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=178, limit=180, resetTimeInSeconds=1430935706, secondsUntilReset=775}, version=3.0.3}
```

What is the reason for the error?

Comment: How do you know you don't have any errors?  You are silently consuming all exceptions.  You should at least call `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block to make sure your call to twitter isn't failing.

Comment: @azurefrog Ya :( this is the error i get Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
 http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b64d2231 or
 http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=309f0452
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b64d2231-309f0452], statusCode=403, message=SSL is required, code=92, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=178, limit=180, resetTimeInSeconds=1430935706, secondsUntilReset=775}, version=3.0.3}. Will update my question

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks mate!! Can you please take a look into the error?

Comment: @azurefrog It states that ssl is required. Is it the cause?

Comment: Yes, it is. At least that's what the exception says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set SSL enabled. Look at this topic for further information: ["SSL is required" exception while requesting OAuthRequest Token using Twitter4J library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742478/ssl-is-required-exception-while-requesting-oauthrequest-token-using-twitter4j)